# How to show list of available cars in list view?

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am having a car model is_available =models.booleanfield(default =False)
Can anyone tell me the query to show only available cars in class list view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to override the [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method of the [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview). The query itself is straightforward:

```
class CarListView(ListView):
    # ...
    model = Car
    # ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(CarListView, self).get_queryset()
        qs = qs.filter(is_available=True)
        return qs
```

Comment: If car is booked its not available how to query that ?i am having car booking model also if car is booked its not availaable . How to do this ?

Comment: So many questions for one little thread. Have you completed one of the numerous django tutorials? Sounds like you need some basics ;)

Comment: Haha i had completed but when i am implementing i am blanked. Its my first project making my own .